# Check if polynomials vectors are linearly indpendent

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to know if $ {1+x,1-x,1-x^2} $ are linearly independent 
i know that i need to check it like

$$ a(1+x)+b(1-x)+c(1-x^2)=0 $$

In my math book
they show the solution
as $$ (a+b+c)+(a-b)x-cx^2=0 $$

but i didnt understand
why i can do this
$$ a+b+c =0 \\
a-b=0 \\
-c=0 $$
isnt it say by doing this that i check different polynomials? $${1,x,x^2}$$
These are different polynomials than those shown in the question, how can I actually do this? i mean how is this answer my quistion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the polynomials $p(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}$ and $q(x)=b_{0}+b_{1}x+b_{2}x^{2}$ they are *equals* if and only if the coefficients are equals, that is,
$$p(x)=q(x)\iff (a_0=b_0) \wedge (a_1=b_1)\wedge (a_2=b_2)$$

In your case in the rhs you have $0+0x+0x^{2}$.

Comment: i need to remember this way of thinking, 0 have many forms, thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you it goes from $$a(1+x)+b(1-x)+c(1-x^2)=0$$ to $$(a+b+c)+(a-b)x-cx^2=0$$ it's using the distributive property. So for example, $a(1+x)=a+ax$. So using this the first equation becomes $$a+ax+b-bx+c-cx^2=0.$$ Now we can add terms in any order so we rearrange to $$(a+b+c)+ax-bx-cx^2=0.$$ Notice I grouped the terms without an $x$, the terms with $x$ and the term with $x^2$ is on its own. Now we factor an $x$ in the middle to get $$(a+b+c)+(a-b)x-cx^2=0.$$ Now we're not checking independence of $1,x,x^2$. All we've shown is that if $$a(1+x)+b(1-x)+c(1-x^2)=0$$ then $(a+b+c)+(a-b)x-cx^2=0$.

Now we will use the crucial fact that $1,x,x^2$ are indeed linearly independent. This is where we get the system of equations in your post and solving that gives us $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: thank you. really helpful answer. but lets say its comes to some a presentation not  of a crucial fact. what whoud l need to do?